# Why does my backup script work when I run it, but not when it's run via cron?

Tags: linux, backup, unix, cron, mongodb

This is my script, `backup_mongo.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
suffix=$(date +%w)
rm /home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix -rf
mkdir /home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix
mongodump -h$1 -u$2 -p$3 -dmydb -o/home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix
```

In my `crontab -e`:

```
0   3  *   *   *    /bin/bash  /home/myuser/myproject/production/backup_mongo.sh  localhost user1 pass1
```

When I run the script normally (executing the command above), the script works and the directory "mydb" gets created in /mongo-$suffix.

However, when I put this in crontab, /mongo-$suffix gets created but the "mydb" directory does not exist. There's nothing in /mongo-$suffix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not have `mongodump` in your `PATH`.  Try using the absolute path to the `mongodump` command.

Comment: If I log in as "myuser", and I just run mongodump, it works. And also, I did put it in /etc/profile. PATH=$PATH:/opt/mongodb/bin export PATH

Comment: Try doing exactly what this answer suggests, putting the full path in the script, or at least execute it as $(which mongodump). Your cron may not be loading anything from your profile.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely a PATH issue but I would recommend to NOT override PATH in your crontab, because it is

- really easy to avoid the behavior
- may be a security risk

Its good bash/sh coding style to define every binary that you want to trigger with with it's full path as variable

```
!#/bin/bash

RSYNC="/usr/bin/rsync"
```

and refer to the variable later.

```
$RSYNC /foo/bar baz
```

There are also certain options to change the user that is executing the crontab. Assuming that there is a user called mongodump that has defined a PATH that includes mongodump, you could become this user and edit it's crontab. Or you could also use

```
/bin/bash /bin/su - mongodump -c /bin/bash /home/myuser/myproject/production/backup_mongo.sh
```

in roots's crontab.

Answer (score 1):

The default PATH for cron is restricted. It is usually `/usr/bin:/bin`. If you want to run anything outside of those directories you have several options

Use full paths to the commands e.g. `/path/to/mongodump/mongodump ...`

Define an extended PATH in the crontab e.g.

```
    PATH=/usr/bin:/bin/:/path/to/mongodump
    0 3 * * * /bin/bash  /home/myuser/myproject/production/backup_mongo.sh  localhost user1 pass1
```

Define the PATH in the script you are running

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/paath/to/mongodump
suffix=$(date +%w)
rm /home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix -rf
mkdir /home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix
mongodump -h$1 -u$2 -p$3 -dmydb -o/home/myuser/backup/mongo-$suffix
```